# Codeigniter controller prevent entire page from reloading when form is validating

Tags: php, codeigniter

Basically, I have my controller function for adding in my case a page but let’s focus on the function:

```
public function add() {
  $this->session->unset_userdata('postID');

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
    // Form Validation
  }
  $this->data['subview'] = 'blah blah';
  $this->load->view('blah blah.php', $this->data);
}
```

Basically when the form is submitted it will still unset the postID in this case, however i want to ensure that if the form is submitted and there are errors that this is missed and it doesn’t redo some of my functions and variables. This is happening for a lot of my content when the form is submitted it re-initiates variables that i want to be ignored.

I also tried the following but it didn’t work either:

```
if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
  $this->session->unset_userdata('postID');
}
```

How do i avoid the entire page being redone when the form is validating as it re-performs all the page load content?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the submit button was pushed by using

```
if($this->input->post('the-name-of-the-submit-button')) {
    $this->session->unset_userdata('postID');
}
```

Basically, `$this->form_validation->run()` checks if the form was submitted *and* if it passed validation rules, whereas the above simply checks if the form was submitted at all.

Comment: But that's the same as !$this->form_validation->run() isn't it?

Comment: No, run() actually verifies the validation rules. The above simply checks if the form was actually submitted or if the page was just loaded.

Comment: I see, i'm just at work at the moment i'll try it very shortly and i'll ensure if it works to let you know and check the answer tick xD Thank you

Comment: No problem. This technique is also useful if you have 2 forms on one page (for example, a login and register form side by side). With this technique, you can easily check which of the forms was submitted and set validation rules accordingly.

Comment: I could also move the form validation to a different page if need be. Just wanted to keep things cleaner.

Comment: It's simpler to keep your form validation in the same function that displays the form. This is the way CI form validation was intended to be used. Otherwise you need to redirect on unsuccessful form submit but you'd lose the validation errors.

Comment: Yes sorry! Ended up not being able to try this until after work today. Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an ajax submission if you don't want the page to refresh:

http://phpsblog.agustinvillalba.com/sending-forms-ajax-codeigniter/

Alternatively, you can fill in the field values so they don't "RESET", ie `<input value="<?php echo $_POST['value'];?>" />`, but ajax is a much better solution.

You can return errors in JSON from your codeigniter controller and display them on your page.

If you do any type of request with your browser, the page is always going to refresh, unless you use ajax/javascript.

Comment: I dont mind the page refreshing, as my autoupdate function is already using AJAX but i want the page refresh with forum submission to ignore the page functionality that's outside the form validation.